# VBA Adding Pivot Fields From Array

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm looking for a way to add multiple fields in the ***Values*** bin of a pivot table (The one below ***Column Labels***). The below code adds my fields to the ***Column Labels*** bin instead. I've tried `RowFields` and `AddToTable` as specified [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCCoe.png). This is what my pivot table should look like (except with a lot more fields from array PF):

[image]

but it's looking like this:

[image]

```
Global PF() As String    
    Sub AddPF()
    Dim LastCol As Integer: LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Dim rngData As Range
            Dim rngDest As Range: Set rngDest = Sheets("PIVOT Lifestyles Rollup").Range("A1")
            Erase PF
            For i = 2 To LastCol
                ReDim Preserve PF(0 To i - 2)
                PF(i - 2) = Cells(2, i).Value
            Next
            ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Set rngData = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
                    ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngDest, _
                    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
            rngDest.Parent.Activate
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).AddFields ColumnFields:=PF
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line of your code then click record macro and add the fields manually. You should be able to clean up the recorded code easily and then add it to what you already had. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

An example to add a data field

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    With .PivotFields("Name of Pivot Field")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Caption = "Pivot Table Column Header"
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "Your desired number format"
    End With
End With
```

If you want to add more value fields, just add the xlDataField and adjust the position